# How can I lookup a value and return the header when an associated cell is less than x?

Tags: excel

I want to lookup a value in another sheet, and when that value has a cell in its row with a value less than or equal to 25 it returns the value of the header of that cell.

Using the picture example, when I lookup value A I want it to return Z as that is where 5 < 25.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MATCH(TRUE,(INDEX($B$2:$D$5,MATCH($G$2,$A$2:$A$5,0),0)<25),0))
```

This is an array formula and needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]